# Laravel 5.2 app/Http routing error when uploaded to a live server

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have uploaded a working Laravel app to shared hosting made the relevant index.php changes required but get the following error message.

> FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58:
>   App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}(): Failed
>   opening required '/home/parsonsgreenmedi/PGM/app/Http/routes.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')

The changes to the index.php file:

```
require __DIR__.'/../PGM/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../PGM/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Permissions at PGM/app/http/ are as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 4096 Aug 17 23:18 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 10 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 4096 Aug 17 23:16 ../ 
drwxr-xr-x  3 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 4096 Aug 17 23:20 controllers/
-rw-r--r--  1 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 1537 Aug 17 23:16 Kernel.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 4096 Aug 17 23:18 Middleware/ 
drwxr-xr-x  2 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 4096 Aug 17 23:18 Requests/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 parsonsgreenmedi parsonsgreenmedi 1286 Aug 18 09:55 routes.php*
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on `routes.php` file? Also, what *required changes* did you make in the `index.php` file?

Comment: I have added the changes above. How would I check the permissions and what should they be @linuxartisan?

Comment: I have tried with 644 and 755

Comment: You may check the permissions using `ls -l` command. Just `cd` down to the required directory before issuing the command. Check permissions on `PGM`, `PGM/app`, `PGM/app/Http`, and `PGM/app/Http/routes.php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121232/discussion-between-linuxartisan-and-james-parsons).